# Eclipse Create Patch is missing for JMeter

Tags: eclipse, svn, jmeter

I wanted to contribute JMeter docs and I'm following [contributing](http://jmeter.apache.org/building.html) manual,

I'm using Eclipse Neon.2 Release (4.6.2),

I download using Subversion and follow the ant process, I'm stuck with patch process:

> **Create a PR using Patch**
>
> Create your patch by Right clicking on Eclipse project and select Team → Create Patch …

When I Right clicking on Eclipse project and select Team I get only **Apply Patch** and not **Create Patch**

How can the patch be created ? is there a workaround?

I found several bugs [fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=367735) but currently, it's not working.

Note: I don't use/have git

**EDIT**: found answer I did `svn diff`:

```
svn diff > fix_ugly_bug.diff
```

And got a file with difference(s):

```
Index: docs/usermanual/component_reference.html
===================================================================
--- docs/usermanual/component_reference.html    (revision 1813248)
+++ docs/usermanual/component_reference.html    (working copy)
@@ -6866,6 +6866,11 @@
 Critical Section Controller takes locks only within one JVM, so if using Distributed testing ensure your use case does not rely on all threads of all JVMs blocking.
 </div>
 <div class="clear"></div>
+<div class="clear"></div>
+<div class="note">
+Using multiple Critical Section Controllers can create a dead lock in a multi threads tests 
+</div>
+<div class="clear"></div>
 <div class="go-top">
 <a href="#">^</a>
 </div>
```

**EDIT**

Not existing menu item also in Eclipse Oxygen Release (4.7.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using svn, then try:

> svn diff > ~/fix_ugly_bug.diff

I use Neon 1, and I have the Create Patch menu item.

Is your project linked to SVN or is it local ?

Comment: I checkout using `svn checkout http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter/trunk/ jmeter`. Diff is working and creating a file with differences

Answer (score 0):

Manual is getting local copy of JMeter trunk. This has no option to create patch

In order to be able to Create Patch and other operation You need to provide repository URL `http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/jmeter` and get JMeter trunk.

Notice this may takes a while until finish operation